# confusion in using global variables declared in one Class to another Class

Tags: java, applet

I have two differennt .java files.

1. form.java  which is an applet which takes user details
2. EmbeddedNeo4j for creating nodes in Neo4j

I want to use the variables which contain the values  that I retrieve from the form.java in EmbeddedNeo4j.

I have already retrieved the values.I want to know how to use that in a different java file.

My form.java file is this

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class form extends JApplet implements ActionListener

{
  String Firstname,Lastname,Birthdate,Gender,State,City,HobbyS,EducationS,OccupationS;
  Object Hobby,Education,Occupation;
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
String HobbyList[]={"Select ANY ONE","Cricket","Hockry","Golf","BasketBall","Football"};
String EducationList[]={"Select ANY ONE","BSc","BCom","BE","B.Tech","MBA","MBBS","PhD"};
String OccupationList[]={"Select ANY ONE","Business","Service","others"};
JPanel panel=new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
JLabel l1=new JLabel("First Name",JLabel.LEFT);
JTextField t1=new JTextField(50);
JLabel l2=new JLabel("Last Name",JLabel.LEFT);
JTextField t2=new JTextField(50);
JLabel l3=new JLabel("Birthday",JLabel.LEFT);
JTextField t3=new JTextField(20);
JRadioButton r1=new JRadioButton("Male");
JRadioButton r2=new JRadioButton("Female");
JLabel l4=new JLabel("State",JLabel.LEFT);
JTextField t4=new JTextField(50);
JLabel l5=new JLabel("City",JLabel.LEFT);
JTextField t5=new JTextField(50);
JLabel l6=new JLabel("Hobby",JLabel.LEFT);
JComboBox jl1=new JComboBox(HobbyList);
JLabel l7=new JLabel("Education",JLabel.LEFT);
JComboBox jl2=new JComboBox(EducationList);
JLabel l8=new JLabel("Occupation",JLabel.LEFT);
JComboBox jl3=new JComboBox(OccupationList);
 JLabel l9=new JLabel("THANK YOU" ,JLabel.LEFT);
JButton submit=new JButton("SUBMIT");


public void init()
{
    add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
    panel.add(l1);
    panel.add(t1);
    panel.add(l2);
    panel.add(t2);
    panel.add(l3);
    panel.add(t3);
   // add(cpanel);
    panel.add(r1);
    panel.add(r2);       
    panel.add(l4);
    panel.add(t4);
    panel.add(l5);
    panel.add(t5);
    panel.add(l6);
    panel.add(jl1);
    panel.add(l7);
     panel.add(jl2);
    panel.add(l8);

    panel.add(jl3);
    panel.add(l9);
    panel.add(submit);


    /*panel.add(c1);
    panel.add(c2);
    panel.add(c3);
    panel.add(c4);*/
    /*panel.add(c2);*/
    Dimension d =new Dimension(20,20);

    l1.setLabelFor(t1);
    l2.setLabelFor(t2);
    t1.setPreferredSize(d);
    t1.setSize(d);
    t1.setMaximumSize(d);
   // t1.setMinimumSize(d);
    t2.setPreferredSize(d);
    t2.setSize(d);
    t2.setMaximumSize(d);

    t3.setPreferredSize(d);
    t3.setSize(d);
    t3.setMaximumSize(d);

    t4.setPreferredSize(d);
    t4.setSize(d);
    t4.setMaximumSize(d);

    t5.setPreferredSize(d);
    t5.setSize(d);
    t5.setMaximumSize(d);

    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel,10,2,20,20,10,10);
    submit.addActionListener(this);
    // provide any initialisation necessary for your JApplet
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        Firstname=t1.getText();
       Lastname=t2.getText();
       Birthdate=t3.getText();
       if(r1.isSelected())
       {Gender=r1.getText();
        }
        else
        Gender=r2.getText();
        State=t4.getText();
        City=t5.getText();
        Hobby=jl1.getSelectedItem();
        Education=jl2.getSelectedItem();
        Occupation=jl3.getSelectedItem();
        HobbyS=Hobby.toString();
       EducationS=Education.toString();
        OccupationS=Occupation.toString();
        repaint();
        //System.out.println(Firstname)
    }
public void start()
{

}
public void stop()
{

}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
   g.setColor(Color.red);

    super.paint(g);
  g.drawString(Firstname,10,560);
     g.drawString(Lastname,10,570);
     g.drawString(Birthdate,10,580);
      g.drawString(Gender,10,590);
       g.drawString(State,10,600);
        g.drawString(City,10,610);
        g.drawString(HobbyS,10,620);
         g.drawString(EducationS,10,630);
          g.drawString(OccupationS,10,640);   
}
public void destroy()
{
    // provide code to be run when JApplet is about to be destroyed.
}


}
```

I want to use String Firstname,Lastname,Birthdate,Gender,State,City,HobbyS,EducationS,OccupationS in EmbeddedNeo4j
Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea where to start, other than by pointing out that Java does not have global variables of any kind, and that having your entire Java program directly extending `JApplet` is generally bad design. Perhaps you should create a data object `Person` that you can use to move information around.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the data Object part.?

Comment: Please work through a basic command-line Java tutorial before jumping to GUI programming. There are a lot of fundamental issues that you need to cover.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) Agree with @chrylis that you should start with easier things.  Applets are a lot more difficult to develop and deploy than they are made out to be.  See the blog article in first comment for my take on it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to create a public getter method for each field you want access:

```
public String getFirstname() {
    return Firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return Lastname;
}
```

I'd also suggest you to name your fields in lowercase, ie: `firstname, lastname` ...

It would also be great encapsulate all these related fields in a class as @chrylis said.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, There is no concept of global variables if you want to copy all data simply make a Person bean class For example:

```
public class Person{

private String fname;
private String mname;
private String lname;
public String getfname() {
    return fname;
}

public String setfname() {
    return fname;
}
//Other getters()&setters();
}
```

and then you can define a **Pesron** class  in **form** class with getter and setter.

If you want to use java class like global varible you can define **Person class** as static variable in a another class as below

```
Public class Globals{
Public static Person FakeGlobalvariablePerson=null;
}
```

It can be used like global variable by calling `Globals.FakeGlobalvariablePerson`  but remember **its not a goodway of coding**.